# How to completely replace a Python module in nixpkgs using an overlay

Tags: python, nix, nixpkgs

I'm trying to replace a Python module (`flask-limiter`) by a completely different build script using `callPackage` in an overlay.

Based on the documentation for Python module overlays, I wrote the overlay like this:

```
final: prev:
rec {
  python = prev.python.override {
    packageOverrides = finalp: prevp: {
      flask-limiter = prevp.callPackage ../flask-limiter.nix {
        inherit (final.python.pkgs) buildPythonPackage pythonOlder typing-extensions asgiref flask hiro limits ordered-set pymemcache pymongo pytest-mock pytestCheckHook rich redis;
      };
    };
  };

  pythonPackages = python.pkgs;

  flask-limiter = final.callPackage ../flask-limiter.nix {
    inherit (final.python.pkgs) buildPythonPackage pythonOlder typing-extensions asgiref flask hiro limits ordered-set pymemcache pymongo pytest-mock pytestCheckHook rich redis;
  };
}
```

(a build script to be ran being put at `../flask-limiter.nix`)

The overlay and the build script do get evaluated, which can be seen because there is an error message when the `inherit` clause is missing some argument needed by the script. However, when I try to install it either directly or through a reverse dependency by `nix-env -i`, it always tries to install the package from `nixpkgs`, not my replacement from the overlay.

I tried to override `python310` and `python310Packages` instead of `python` and `pythonPackages`, but it did not make a difference.